# how to support angular 6 library using ng add

Tags: angular

I created a library using Angular 6 library feature..
I want it to support ng add so that who ever wants to use it can do ng add myawesomelib and consume..
there are articles around that which are pretty complicated , https://nitayneeman.com/posts/making-an-addable-angular-package-using-schematics/

Are there any easier way to support schematics for ng add for a library?